# jquery .load() is loading file twice (i.e., grabs two copies instead of one)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Onclick, the .load() callback fires twice, and, two identical files get loaded.

```
var fetch = $this.attr('href')+' #fetchable';
$('div').load(fetch,'', function(){
    console.log('Done.'); // this fires twice
});
```

Network tab -

```
b.htm?_=1451867642174
b.htm?_=1451867642175
```

Console -

```
(2) Done.
```

Ideas? I just want it to load once, obviously. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, the actual selector I'm using is not 'div' but something with an ID.

Comment: Please show all the relevant code wrapping what is shown. Far too many unknowns based on the small snippet shown. Sounds like you are enabling a click handler more than once

Comment: ^^ You're correct; after reading your comment, I investigated and found that it's a .one(animationEnd) problem, not a .load() problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was using animationend along with webkitanimationend, and, it was therefore firing off twice since Chrome will process both.